# How to determine if $x$ does not belong to $L \in NP$ in a finite number of steps

Tags: computational-complexity, decision-problems

I'd prefer to stick to the "deterministic" definition of NP, i.e:

-A language $L\subseteq {0, 1}^*$ is in $NP$ if there exists a polynomial $p : N \rightarrow N$ and a polynomial-time $Turing$ $Machine$ $M$ such that for every $x \in {\{0, 1\}}^*$ (that  is, the set of all possible binary strings),

$$x \in L \Leftrightarrow \exists u \in {\{0, 1\}}^{p(|x|)} s.t. M(x, u) = 1,$$

taken from the book by Arora and Barak.

The question is: how can I check that a given $x$ does not belong to $L$ in a finite number of steps?

Comment: What are your thoughts, and what have you tried? Keep in mind that you don't have to have an _efficient_ algorithm for checking, just _an_ algorithm.

Comment: It's not like I'm dealing with a specific problem; it's a general question. 
If the problem is to check if $x \in L$, I could just run over all the possible values of $u$, and I'm assured to decide the problem within a finite number of steps.
But, given that $NP\subset R$, shouldn't be possible to verify that $x$ does NOT belong to $L$ always within a finite number of steps?

Comment: If you ran over all the possible values of $u$ and never got $M(x,u)=1$ then...

Comment: The set of all possible values of $u$ doesn't seem finite to me. So I cannot just run over all of them. Maybe I'm missing something more basic, but I honestly don't konw what

Comment: Generally when you're given a language in $P$ you're also given a _witness_ for it — that is to say, a specific polynomial and TM such that the conditions for being in $P$ hold. If all you have is a guarantee rather than a witness, then I suspect the problem isn't solvable.

Comment: Aren't all $NP$ problems decidable?

Comment: @ygh If a problem is in $NP$ it's decidable — but the problem of 'does _this_ Turing Machine run in polynomial time?' is undecidable.

Comment: If $NP$ is decidable, then I should be able to determine in a finite amount of steps if $x\not\in L$. Is that true?